# How to highlight returned words

Tags: python-2.7

I need to search a keyword from a text, select sentences surrounding the keyword, and then highlight only the keyword.

```
p = re.compile(r'(([^\.]*\.){2}[^\.]*succession[^\.]*\.([^\.]*\.){2})')
p2 = re.findall(p, text)
```

The above code finds two sentences before and after the sentence containing succession. Now, I need to highlight "succession". I just need to make the keyword bold. I don't care about the color at all. Is there any simple way to do that? May be using re.sub?

```
re.sub(r'succession', ' succession ', p2)
```

Comment: Do you use specific markup / GUI? Please let us know what it is.

Comment: I guess I don't use markup. Suppose my input is just several lines of texts. Is there anyway to make some words bold?

Comment: "bold" doesn't mean anything unless you tell us how you intend to display it. Is it a web page? Is it a Windows application? Is it on the terminal? Do you want to print it to a printer and make it bold?

Comment: I guess I know nothing to answer your question. What I want is suppose I have a text : "I am a boy. You are a girl." From the text, I just want to make "boy" highlighted. I was looking for regular expression to do so. Is there any way to replace a word to a bolded word? Sorry if this sounds really stupid.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`termcolor`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor) module to do this.

```
>>> import termcolor
>>> termcolor.cprint('yourText', color=None, attrs=['bold'])
yourText
```

#### Screenshot of my terminal:

[image]

Comment: I got an error:  No module named termcolor. I use python 2.7

Comment: you have to install the module first

Comment: I want to highlight only a word in several sentences.

Answer (score 0):

If your output is on a a Unix-standard (VT-100) compatible terminal, then use VT-100 escape sequences to make text bold.  For example:

```
print('The process of \033[1msuccession\033[0m can be dangerous.')
```

Here, `\033[1m` starts the bold output and `\033[0m` cancels it.

#### Examples of using `re` to make selected text bold

As a script on the command line:

[image]

In the python interpreter:

[image]

These screenshots were taken in a Xterm terminal running under X11.

#### Another approach with broader compatibility

For greater compatibility and ease of use, consider installing the python package [fabulous](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fabulous) which offers bold/colored text.

Comment: When I put that in re.sub as follows: re.sub(r'boy','\033[1mboy\033[0m',b), I got "I am a \x1b[1mboy\x1b[0m". Is there a way to make a word highlighted using regular expression.

Comment: @JimmyAhn Try with the `print` command.  I see the same as you if I display on the terminal but I see bold if I `print` the string. (If you are using this, I can that you are on a Unix-style terminal, right?)

Comment: Suppose I have a text: "I am a boy. You are a girl." From these two sentences, I need to highlight, for example, "boy" keeping other words unchanged. I need to return the whole text including the bolded word so I cannot just use print option.

Comment: @JimmyAhn I just took a screenshot of my output and added it to the answer.  It is a different sentence but same idea.  It was done on an `xterm` terminal under X11.

Comment: Thanks, John. But I don't understand "It was done on an xterm terminal under X11". I am really a beginner, John.

Comment: @JimmyAhn OK.  Let's start from the beginning.  What operating system are you using?  Windows, Linux, Mac OSX?

Comment: I still get the same thing as below:>>> import re
>>> a=re.sub(r'boy','\033[1mboy\033[0m','I am a boy')
>>> print(a)
I am a [1mboy[0m

Comment: @JimmyAhn I tried that in the python terminal and I just added a screenshot of it to the answer: it shows bold.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: @JimmyAhn That's important.  That explains why your terminal is not reacting as a standard Unix terminal would.  Since I am not familiar with Windows, I hope that someone else comes here who can help.